Mass of a Spring in Spring-Mass System
I’m working with the spring-mass system and we just derived the period of the oscillations.  My question is:
Does the mass of the spring itself change the period in any way? And if so, is there a way to find by how much?
Thanks!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(spring-mass_system)

What have you tried?
